# Valet returns 404 not found

Tags: laravel-valet, valet

I'm trying to get Valet to work but all my sites return `404 - Not found`.

My project folder is named `Webb`, inside is a folder named `ogge`. The path is `~/Desktop/Webb/ogge`.

### Valet is parked in my project folder, the `~/.config/valet/config.json` contains the following:

```
{
    "tld": "test",
    "paths": [
        "/Users/oscarbjurestrand/.config/valet/Sites",
        "/Users/oscarbjurestrand/Desktop/Webb/ogge",
        "/Users/oscarbjurestrand/Desktop/Webb"
    ]
}
```

### I have linked the `ogge` project and `valet links` returns this:

[image: screenshot displaying what "valet links" returns]

### These are the things I've tried

- Restarted nginx and dnsmasq with `brew services restart --all`.
- Reinstalled Valet, Composer and Brew.
- Restarted my computer.
- Restarted Valet.
- `brew services list` returns ngninx, dnsmasq and php as started.
- I can ping ogge.test without any issues.
- I saw [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/333) and tried everything mentioned but without any luck.

What is wrong with my Valet?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your website address to your `hosts` file, and it will work normally.

You can find the file under (for Lunix):

```
/etc/hosts
```

For Windows under:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And add your records for your website like to the `hosts` file like:

```
127.0.0.1 ogge.test
```